# Node.js Jade: Nested 'for' loop not working

Tags: node.js, for-loop, nested, inline, pug

With the Jade template engine in Node.js, I am trying to use nested JavaScript to populate a table with elements.
This is what I want to achieve:

```
<tr class="darkTableRow">
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 0</td>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="darkTableRow">
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 0</td>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="darkTableRow">
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 0</td>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 1</td>
</tr>
```

The Jade code which I am using is this:

```
- for (var g = 0; g < GPU_count; g++)
    tr.darkTableRow
    - for (var v = 0; v < 2; v++) 
        td.vcTextValue= 'value: ' + v
```

And this is the HTML which the template has been outputting:

```
<tr class="darkTableRow"></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 0</td>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="darkTableRow"></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 0</td>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="darkTableRow"></tr>
<tr>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 0</td>
    <td class="vcTextValue">value: 1</td>
</tr>
```

As you can see, an empty  is being rendered and it's class is set to `darkTableRow`. This is not what I want.

So am I writing the Jade code incorrectly? I do not understand how to format inline JavaScript code. I don't know what the dashes are for, and if curly braces make a difference in the template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- for (var g = 0; g < GPU_count; g++) {
      tr.darkTableRow
          - for (var v = 0; v < 2; v++) 
              td.vcTextValue= 'value: ' + v
- }
```

The dashes are the ugly way to do it... Jade has some internal iterators that you can use without the dashes... the dashes mean "the rest of this line is pure Javascript"

It looks like your issue here was the lack of indent "into" the tr... so it made the tr... then closed it, and then made a new fake tr to hold the td's you tried to then spit out.